# Add gradient for all borders of textarea with bootstrap material design

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I'm using [Material Design for Bootstrap](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) and I want to change a textarea for it to have all borders to work with the gradient, instead of working only with the bottom border.

I have started to change the class `is-focused`, but I'm not able to implement all the effects correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap material design uses a narrow background-image as the bottom border.

It'll be tricky to create a gradient background image that runs along the borders of an element. Instead. you can try animating the borders itself like:

```css
.form-group textarea {
  border: 2px solid #D2D2D2;
  transition: border-color 1s;
  background-image:none;
}
.is-focused textarea {
  border: 3px solid #009688;
}
```

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxVJXX)